Frattini Factors in GAP
I am trying to find a group in GAP. I know it is of order 96, so I wanted to Check some of the listed groups of that order after the command "SmallGroupsInformation(96)". These are "sorted by their Frattini Factors" and I am not sure what that should mean. Concretely, what would mean that the symmetry group $S_{10}$ has Frattini Factors $[6,8,9]$ for GAP?

This does not answer the stated question but might actually answer the question you really should be asking: this doesn't sound like the best way to find your group in GAP. Much better would be to input it in GAP somehow (how do you "have" this group? as a permutation group? Matrix group?) and then just ask GAP to identify it. (I'm not sure the exact command in GAP but it should be something like IdentifyGroup(G).)

Also, this from the Carpentries-style lesson on GAP may be relevant: https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups.html

The Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$ of a group $G$ is the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$, and is always a normal subgroup of $G$. By 'Frattini factor', the quotient $G/\Phi(G)$ is meant. So, in the Small Groups Library, the groups of order $96$ are sorted based on what group $G/\Phi(G)$ is.
For example, the command SmallGroupsInformation(96) mentions that
There are 231 groups of order 96.
They are sorted by their Frattini factors.
   [...]
   185 - 195 have Frattini factor [ 48, 48 ].
   [...]

This means that the groups with ID $[96,i]$ for $185 \leq i \leq 195$ will have Frattini factor with ID $[48,48]$:
gap> G := SmallGroup( 96, 190 );;
gap> F := FrattiniSubgroup( G );;
gap> IdGroup( G/F );
[ 48, 48 ]

If you are looking for a particular group, you can quickly select groups (or their ID's) satisfying certain criteria using AllSmallGroups or IdsOfAllSmallGroups. For example, if you know the group you are looking for is nilpotent but not abelian, you could use
gap> IdsOfAllSmallGroups( 96, IsNilpotentGroup, true, IsAbelian, false );
[ [ 96, 45 ], [ 96, 47 ], [ 96, 48 ], [ 96, 49 ], [ 96, 50 ], [ 96, 51 ], [ 96, 52 ], [ 96, 53 ], [ 96, 54 ],
  [ 96, 55 ], [ 96, 56 ], [ 96, 57 ], [ 96, 58 ], [ 96, 60 ], [ 96, 61 ], [ 96, 62 ], [ 96, 63 ], [ 96, 162 ],
  [ 96, 163 ], [ 96, 164 ], [ 96, 165 ], [ 96, 166 ], [ 96, 167 ], [ 96, 168 ], [ 96, 169 ], [ 96, 170 ],
  [ 96, 171 ], [ 96, 172 ], [ 96, 173 ], [ 96, 174 ], [ 96, 175 ], [ 96, 177 ], [ 96, 178 ], [ 96, 179 ],
  [ 96, 180 ], [ 96, 181 ], [ 96, 182 ], [ 96, 183 ], [ 96, 184 ], [ 96, 221 ], [ 96, 222 ], [ 96, 223 ],
  [ 96, 224 ], [ 96, 225 ] ]

